# Objective-C nullability for output parameters

Tags: objective-c

I'm adding nullability specifiers to a class, and I have some pointer-to-pointer output parameters, like `(NSString**)`, because the method returns multiple objects. How do I specify nullability for that?

For these particular cases, I want callers to not pass in NULL, but I don't care if they pass a pointer to a nil variable (or rather, that's expected).

At first I tried `(nonnull NSString**)`, and after a couple of rounds of Xcode's suggested fixes, ended with `(NSString* _Nonnull *)`, but there's still a warning on the second *, "Pointer is missing nullability type specifier", with no suggested fix.

Comment: Keep in mind: Nullability is important for Swift, not for pure Objective-C.

Comment: Yeah, the reason I'm doing this is I want to access this class from Swift.

Comment: There you have it: Poison code in a good language for compatibility in a bad language. :-]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have two pointers so you need two nullability specifiers.

```
- (void)someMethod:(NSString * _Nullable * _Nonnull)out
```

This means you must pass in a non-null pointer but you may get back a null result.

This will fail:

```
[someObject someMethod:nil];
```

This will work:

```
NSString *result = nil;
[someObject someMethod:&result];
```

Comment: This somehow isn't working for me. Xcode always complains when I pass in a nil to the someMethod:


`warning: null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument [-Wnonnull]
    [newClass someMethod:nil];
                      ^                   ~~~
1 warning generated.`


However if I change both the qualifier to _Nullable, it stops complaining (as expected). I still would like to use two distinct qualifiers, `* _Nullable * _Nonnull` but it's not working