# Handle _Nonnull or Nullable with multi-level pointer type

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-nullability

How to associate nullability keywords with multi-level pointer types in following declaration for `(NSError **)error`?

`- (void)loadSessionForUserId:(nonnull NSString *)userId error:(NSError **)error {
   ...
}`

I want to make error nullable and get rid of `“Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (__nonnull or __nullable)”`

Error variant with Xcode11: `nullability keyword 'nullable' cannot be applied to multi-level pointer type 'NSError *__autoreleasing  _Nullable *'`

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618830/objective-c-nullability-for-output-parameters

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting a warning, or error if treat-warning-as-error is on for project, on Xcode 9. Use this format for multi-level pointers:

## Solution:

`error:(NSError *_Nullable* _Nullable)error`

## Other error variations:

a) With `error:(NSError **  _Nonnull)error`
Results in compile time error
`Nullability keyword 'nullable' cannot be applied to multi-level pointer type 'NSError *__autoreleasing *’`

b) with `error:(NSError * _Nonnull *)error`
Results in compile time error
`Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified)`

c) with `error:(NSError ** _Nullable)error`
Results in compile time error `Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified)`

Open Radar for NSError** without a nullability type shows as a warning which can't be suppressed
http://www.openradar.me/21766176

Comment: Ah; you're not adding `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` and `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END` around your interface. Typically that is preferred over individually marking every parameter. With it, you'll get the expected `NSError **` behavior without having to mark it. ("assume nonnull" actually assumes null for indirects, because that's almost always correct.)