# NSError** 'Potential null dereference.....'

Tags: objective-c, non-nullable

Giving the following example:

```
- (BOOL) doSomething: (NSError**) pError
{
    *pError = [NSError ....];
}
```

Analyzer will return the following error:

> Potential null dereference.  According to coding standards in 'Creating and Returning NSError Objects' the parameter may be null.

To which the suggestion would be to change this to:

```
- (BOOL) doSomething: (NSError**) pError
{
    if(pError)
    {
        *pError = [NSError ....];
    }
}
```

But I would prefer to add a nonnull attribute to the error parameter to discourage the use of passing a null. I cannot figure out how to get the arguments to this correct. Is it possible for a double pointer to have a nonnull attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I would prefer to add a nonnull attribute to the error parameter to discourage the use of passing a null.

The syntax you're looking for is shown in various Stack Overflow answers, such as [Objective-C nullability for output parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618830/objective-c-nullability-for-output-parameters). So you could declare, for example:

```
(NSError * _Nullable * _Nonnull)
```

...and the desired warning would appear:

[image]

I would suggest instead, however, that you simply stop preferring that. The analyzer is quite right about the pattern; you should listen to what it's telling you.

The standard full pattern for calling a method that returns NSError by indirection is, for example:

```
NSString* path = // ... whatever;
NSStringEncoding enc = // ... whatever;
NSError* err = nil;
NSString* s =
    [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:enc error:&err];
if (nil == s) // oops! something went wrong...
```

But let's say I'm absolutely certain that this is going to work. Then it is legal to say:

```
NSString* path = // ... whatever;
NSStringEncoding enc = // ... whatever;
NSString* s =
    [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:enc error:nil];
```

You should not rule this out; it's reasonable and normal.

Comment: Even this is – of course – a great answer, I want to add, that `nil` is not `NULL`. `nil` is always an reference to an (no) *object*, while `NSError**` does *not* point to an (no) *object*.

Comment: `I would suggest instead, however, that you simply stop preferring that.`. Thanks, honestly I needed that beat into my head and your comment did just that. I also appreacheate that instead of just saying that you took the time to answer the underlying question (although I will follow the proper solution).